Is there any chance to render a form in django as a plain text?
im rendering a form in django using a forms.py file, the thing is i did my design with only pure html/css and i  got in this way:

<form action="">
                <label for="username"> Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="" class="input" >
                <label for="password"> Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password id="" class="input">
                
            </form>

and i got my styles to work in that way
but then, when im passing it through Django in his function from views.py and in the html file rendering it as
{{ user_form }}
i got this
<form method="post">
            <div>
    <label for="id_username">Username:</label>

<div class="helptext" id="id_username_helptext">Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</div>

<input type="text" name="username" maxlength="150" class="input" required aria-describedby="id_username_helptext" id="id_username">
    
</div>

  <div>
    <label for="id_email">Email address:</label>



<input type="email" name="email" maxlength="254" class="input" id="id_email">
    
</div>

  <div>
    <label for="id_first_name">Full Name:</label>



<input type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="150" class="input" id="id_first_name">
    
</div>

  <div>
    <label for="id_password">Password:</label>



<input type="password" name="password" class="input" required id="id_password">
    
</div>

  <div>
    <label for="id_password2">Repeat Password:</label>



<input type="password" name="password2" class="input" required id="id_password2">
    
      
    
</div>
            <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="yIK2Cm5pnsIuQzwGZkl0CK5iX2tdfgQP2L8W17D5vEbbImrzVTyH1nW52pyj70E1">

            <p><input type="submit" value="Create my account"> </p>

            </form>

which is broking my defined css styles. so how can render this form as i want in the way i define in above? (maybe y'all could think "bro just adapt it" but im weak in css so for that im asking)
Also, is there a link to read about the methods of the form variable? i was looking for in the django documentation but i found nothing yet. thank a lot

The simplest way I've found was to render using {{ user_form.as_div }}, which puts each label/field in a div but without an id, like this:
<form>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</form>

But since each div no longer had any id, I selected by being a child of the form tag, i.e., in styles.css:
form > div { my styles }

